# Stop JSON attach on ASP.net MVC3, Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I saw lots and lots error on Elmah

```
System.ArgumentException
Invalid JSON primitive: .

System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

From the stacks, seems the code never reach any part of code that I wrote, so I wonder why ASP.net engine just deserialize the request and give error, is this because of http-header imply the type is json?

```
ALL_RAW Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 9101 Content-Type: application/json Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Anyway, is there a way to change MVC setting to stop answer this kind of request (the IP constant change, URL constant change, domain constant change, so now I do not know how to block it :(

Comment: The header doesn't imply anything, it explicitly says the request is gzip encoded application/json. Is your application making the request? Or are you worried it's some kind of harmful spambot?

Comment: no, its not, it's from wild range of IP, and domain even different (my application domain is catch all, on IP, so any domain can visit, and the domain on this request even not exist), and the request path different time by time. Almost 1 question per second, like DDOS attach

Comment: Show us the request in question (gzip-decoded, json-beautified). If it's just request spam, it's a question for webmasters, not SO. :)